# AutoIT Check If Process is running on Remote PC

Tags: process, autoit, wmi-query

I currently have some AutoIT code that will terminate a process on a remote machine, but I'm needing to find a way to add a check to see if the process is running first.  After spending some time sifting through the AutoIT forums and google, I'm at a loss.  Here is what I currently have:

```
Func EndProc()
$oWMIService = ObjGet("winmgmts:\\" & $ipAddress & "\root\CIMV2")

If Not IsObj($oWMIService) Then
    MsgBox(48, "ERROR", "Couldn't locate the computer. Please make sure you've selected the correct computer and try again.")
    Return
EndIf

Dim $handle, $colProc, $cProc
$cProc = $oWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = "' & $ProcessToKill & '"')

For $oProc In $cProc
    $oProc.Terminate()
 Next
If $handle Then
    Return $handle
Else
    Return 0
EndIf
EndFunc ; Func EndProc()
```

Comment: Are you looking for confirmation of whether this works? Or suggestions for improvement? Please clarify.

Comment: I apologize I wasn't clear.  I know the above code works.  I'm looking to see if someone can help me add a check to see if the process I want to kill is running first, before it tries to terminate the process.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the examples [here](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/132420-checking-if-powerpoint-process-is-working-on-a-remote-computer/), there are a number of different ways to use WMI via AutoIT to retrieve the list of processes running remotely and filter on the ones you care about.

Alternatively, calling [PSList](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682) through AutoIT could prove useful as well.

Comment: That put me down the right path, I appreciate it.  Thanks Paul.